# Easy to install/maintain web-based project management software

Tags: open-source, project-management

We are currently looking for a web-based project management software with the following requirements:

1. Open source.
2. Easy installation, configuration and upgrading (As much as possible).
3. Progress tracking (Timesheets?)
4. Adding both fixed- and open-time projects.
5. Flexible user assignment and management.
6. Git integration (Optional, not required at all).

Please do not recommend Trac and Redmine, we did not consider them due to #2.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why Trac and Redmine aren't an option?

Comment: Redmine is a serious pain when installing it. Trac is a serious pain configuring it. We think of them that way because in our team we do not have focus on system administration and installation. That's why we need something easy to install at the least.

Comment: And by the way we are trying EGroupware which is way better in installation  and configuration.

Answer (score 1):

In that case, I propose [WeKan](https://wekan.github.io/), it is a very powerful and very simple tool at the same time.

In its [features](https://github.com/wekan/wekan/wiki/Features) you can see that it meets your needs.

And, of course, it is open-source.

Comment: Thanks. But we are trying OrangeScrum for now.

Comment: You are wellcome! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The [Freedcamp](https://freedcamp.com/) solution is a very powerful Project Management System, that combines ease and power.

The main caracteristics are:

- Web-based
- List item
- iOS App version
- Time tracking
- Discussion boards
- There is a [free version](https://freedcamp.com/pricing)

[image]

Comment: "Open source" is the first requirement. Freedcamp is not open source.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Well I always confuse "Open source" with "Free" and this one is no different, I meant free.

Comment: Here is a great explanation of freeware vs. open source: http://opensourcestrategies.blogspot.jp/2005/09/freeware-vs-shareware-vs-open-source.html . There is another thing called "Free software" but Freedcamp is not that either, Freedcamp is just "free as in beer not as in freedom".